# Symfony 4 - An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar

Tags: php, symfony4

I'm working under Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu 18.04), apache2 and php 7.2

When I generate a Symfony 3 project the toolbar is generated but with Symfony 4.2.5 the debugging toolbar does not show even with a fersh install.

I tried this solutions:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
chmod -R 777 var/cache
```

and

```
[sudo] a2enmod rewrite
[sudo] service apache2 restart
```

And changed my .htaccess :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

But I still got the same message for the toolbar with this message at the end of the page:

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar.

Comment: I did not change any thing, and today the toolbar is back!

Comment: Hi @zied-alaya, I had to change a few lines of code in the composer.json file. Please refer to my comment here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432536/symfony-update-from-4-2-to-4-3-caused-web-profiler-to-break#comment104495374_56443122

Answer (score 0):

I'm working under Windows and i had had similar problem,in my case the .htaccess file was not present in the public folder after installing the apache-pack or before,even after installing the profiler,so I just copy/paste the htaccess code from another site like https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/793/how-to-configure-a-virtualhost-in-xampp-3-3-2-for-a-symfony-4-project ... hope this helped