# Symfony update from 4.2 to 4.3 caused Web Profiler to break

Tags: symfony, composer-php, upgrade, symfony-4.3

I ran `composer update` and now am getting a slew of deprecation warnings:

```
> [2019-06-03 18:08:41] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt".
> {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"9354bc"},"request_uri":"http://local
> host:8080/_wdt/9354bc","method":"GET"} [] [2019-06-03 18:08:42]
> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\RuntimeError:
> "Impossible to access an attribute ("nb_errors") on a string variable
> ("O:39:"Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Data":6:{s:45:"ymf
> ony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Data
```

The **Web Profiler Toolbar** is broken with this error:

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar.

And yet when I do `bin/console --version` I am getting:

```
Symfony 4.3.0 (env: dev, debug: true)
```

What gives? What about the *composer.json* file gives **Composer** the ability to update to `4.3` even?

---

Here is my current *composer.json*:

```
{
  "type": "project",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.0",
    "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^1.17",
    "iio/libmergepdf": "~3.0",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^3.5",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^5.0",
    "simplisti/jasper-starter": "dev-master",
    "symfony/asset": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/ldap": "^4.0",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
    "symfony/options-resolver": "^4.0",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
    "phing/phing": "^2.14",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^4.0",
    "symfony/debug": "^4.0",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.7",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": {
      "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "src/Legacy/"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
      "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
      "security-checker security:check": "script"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "id": "01C3XNQSBGC1MSASSGCW6TKGXB",
      "allow-contrib": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What version did you update from?  I made a quick test on a fresh 4.3 project without encountering these warnings.

Comment: 4.2.9 on Friday...now somehow 4.3.0?!? Can you see anything obvious in my composer.json in OP?

Comment: Bit of a mystery to say the least.  I took a fresh 4.2.8 and ran composer update.  As expected, I got 4.2.9.  Ran update again and it stayed at 4.2.9.  You do have some ^4.0's in your composer.json file.  Mine does not.  I seldom have much luck recovering from messed up composer.json files.  Might consider installing a fresh 4.2.9 project then merge your additional dependencies into the out of the box composer.json.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking...thanks for confirming my hunch or assumption haha :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open composer.json. Update all the 4.2 references to 4.3. You probably have symfony/web-profiler-bundle in there as 4.2 instead of 4.3. Save, then composer update.

Comment: Everything is pretty much 4.2.* not sure how 4.3.0 even got in there? I've deleted /vendor and `composer install` multiple times...can you see anything obvious in my composer.json added to OP?

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks a bunch @afessler! I was upgrading from symfony version 4.2.* to 4.4.*. Before I ran the composer update script I only changed the `"require"` from 4.2.* to 4.4.*. Among other problems I faced, I also need to see the web profiler which was not showing. Following this instruction I had to change all references to 4.2.* to 4.4.* to get everything working again. I had to change `use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;` to `use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;` for my repository classes as well with this upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem in `vendor/symfony/web-profiler-bundle/Resources/views/Collector/form.html.twig`

Trying to access `collector.data.nb_errors`, but `collector.data` is `null`.

Comment: Did you found a solution? Got the same problem but have no clue what to do, to fix it

Comment: @rebru the [accepted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443122/10507793) worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late but if you want to keep symfony 4.2, you just have to replace all yours symfony's dependencies from "^4" to "4.2.*" in composer.json

For example, in your json you have
`"symfony/ldap": "^4.0"`, so when you ran `composer show`, you'll see that some dependencies where upgrade to 4.3 with a `composer update`.